# Email not sending from background in android?

Tags: android, email

I am sending email in background in my app using code mention in this post: [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124). I put a debug option in properties to check and verify email sending process like this:

```
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
```

and when i send mail from my app it shows following message like this "Please log-in to your account from you browser" i checked my password and email they are correct, please help me to figure out the actual problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you Authenticate as sender's and then send email in your code like this using javax.mail

```
props.put("mail.smtp.user", "YOUREMAIL@gmail.com");
       props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
       props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
       props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       //props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", d_port);
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
       props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

       try {
           Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
           Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);     
           MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

           msg.setSubject(m_subject);
           msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("YOUREMAIL@gmail.com"));
           msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("DESTINATION_EMAIL@gmail.com"));

           Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  

           String data=" Hello There.";




           //attach Image
           BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(pathUserImg); 
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
        messageBodyPart.setFileName("IMG_NAME.png"); 

        //attach String Data
```

MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();
  messageBodyPart1.setText("data:  "+data);

```
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1); 

           msg.setContent(multipart );  

          Transport.send(msg);


       } catch (Exception mex)
       {
           mex.printStackTrace();
           Log.v("TAG", " Email Not Sent "+mex.getMessage());
       }


   private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator
   {
       public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           return new PasswordAuthentication(YOURrEMAIL@gmail.com@gmail.com", "YourPASSWORD");
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment,i am following exact procedure for sending mail as i mention in my post it is not working as well.

Comment: can put your code here? then i can try to find out what is wrong

Comment: also check for permissions

Comment: Hi am adding all necessary permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> and code is exact same as this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124

Comment: do you get any exceptions in your logcat ? if you are getting NetWorkOnMainThread then you should do email sending process in AsyncTask. I would like to see your logcat if any exception occurs.